# SVN Password when executing maven from Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu, svn, sonarqube

For a given task I need to execute an SVN blame via maven (the sonar:sonar goal does that, to be more exact), typically from eclipse. This worked fine, until today, when my password to the SVN server was changed. Eclipse reacted as expected, asked for the new password and that was it.

But now the maven execution fails with...

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project xxx: Error when executing blame for file src/main/java/etc/something.java: svn: E170001: Authentication required for '<http://svn.ourserver.net:80> Subversion Repositories' -> [Help 1]
```

I already tried to reset the password of the ubuntu subversion installation (clearing .subversion, then checking something out - worked fine, asked for password, now checking out via `svn` doesn't require password anymore) but that didn't work for maven, same error as before.

Unfortunately I have no idea where maven gets the (old, now incorrect) password from, so that I can change it there. Obviously it's neither the eclipse settings nor the subversion configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the sonar:sonar goal does

This was the solution: Not maven does execute the svn blame, but SonarQube does, maven only displays the error. Which is why obviously (now) the old password was stored in the SonarQube svn settings. Changing it there solved the problem.